# In emacs term-mode (not shell-mode), how can we edit a command just like we type C-x C-e in real terminal

Tags: shell-command, term

In real terminal, if we type `C-x C-e`, we can [edit a typed command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html) using an editor.  Could have similar function in emacs term-mode?  After typing a shortcut, I would like to edit the current command in a new buffer (e.g., similar to the helm pop-up window) instead of opening a nested emacs.  Is there any emacs package written for that?  Thanks.